# How can I only document a subfolder with GhostDoc?

Tags: documentation, subdirectory, ghostdoc

I am trying to build a HelpFile in GhostDoc.  It only gives me the option to document entire Projects.  I only want to document a sub folder within a project.  How can I do this?

[image]

I see no options to select a subfolder.  If I right click on a project, no options come up.  Does anyone know how to only document a subfolder?

Answer (score 0):

While GhostDoc doesn't directly support the help docs for a folder, there is a workaround you should try.

You can add a tag on top of the namespace in all of the source files under that folder similar to

```
<tags>MyFolderDocs</tags
```

And then list MyFolderDocs in the "Tagged with" filter of the Help Configuration window on your screenshot.

I hope this helps.